# Find class value inside a List

Tags: c#

The user will input a `Lis<People>` with `Name`, `Age` and `Address`, i.e.

```
PeopleList.Add(new People { 
  Name    = name, 
  Age     = age, 
  Address = address 
});
```

After the `PeopleList` is done, the user can *search* for a `Name` and view the `Age` and `Address` with it.

I am having a problem on how to *search* within `PeopleList` for a specific `Name`.

```
string searchName = Console.ReadLine();

if (PeopleList.Contains(new People {
    Name = searchName
})) {
    //Display name, age, address here
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Name not found");
}
```

Comment: Use System.Linq. `PeopleList.Find(p => p.Name == searchName)`.

Comment: how about multiple entries with the same name? Since you did not use the linq tag, have you considered ot even tried using a loop over the collection? and comparing the name?

Comment: Off topic, but BEWARE! when you use the method contains in this line : `PeopleList.Contains(new People {...` you give it a entirely new instance of `People`. Since you did not specify a comparing method, contains will compare the equality of each instance with the new one. It will not compare the variable `Name` ! This statement will return always false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Linq `FirstOrDefault()` to determine the first element, in case one exists.

```
string searchName = Console.ReadLine();
People result = PeopleList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == searchName);
if (result != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0}, age: {1}, address:{2}", result.Name, result.Age, result.Address);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name not found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try *query* the collection with a help of *Linq*

```
using System.Linq;

...

string result = PeopleList
  .Where(item => item.Name == searchName)
  .Select(found => $"Name: {found.Name}; Age: {found.Age}; Address: {found.Address}") 
  .FirstOrDefault() ?? "Name not found";

Console.Write(result);
```

If you want to show not the *first* but *all* items found, you can `Join` them:

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.Newline, PeopleList
  .Where(item => item.Name == searchName)
  .Select(found => $"Name: {found.Name}; Age: {found.Age}; Address: {found.Address}")
);

result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) 
  ? "Name not found" 
  : result;

Console.Write(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

## What's happening

The signature for `Contains` is `public static bool Contains<TSource> (...);` and it only gives you a yes/no answer. In order to display the matching object you need one of the methods that return matching objects, not just yes/no if they are found. These methods are `Where`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, and more.

---

Note: The class should be called `Person` since it represents data about a single person, not about multiple people.

```
Person person;
List<Person> people;
```

## Solution

BTW. @fubo was first but I think this is more complete

```
var searchName = Console.ReadLine();
var results = PeopleList
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
if (results.Any())
{
    foreach (var person in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found: {person.Name}");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name not found");
}
```

---

## Test

### Code

```
class Person { public string Name { get; set; } }
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var PeopleList = new[] { new Person { Name = "marneee" }, new Person { Name = "Mark" } };
    while (true)
    {
        var searchName = Console.ReadLine();
        var results = PeopleList
            .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .ToList();
        if (results.Any())
        {
            foreach (var person in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found: {person.Name}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name not found");
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
mar
Found: marneee
Found: Mark
marn
Found: marneee
```